# How to test http request in elm

Tags: http, elm

I have a request builder like this:

```
login : { r | usernameOrEmail : String, password : String } -> Http.Request Token
login { usernameOrEmail, password } =
  let
    body =
      Http.jsonBody <|
        Encode.object
          [ ("username_or_email", Encode.string usernameOrEmail)
          , ("password", Encode.string password)
          ]
  in
    Http.post (apiUrl "/auth/login/") body Token.decoder
```

I can use it by calling send from *elm-lang/http*:

`Http.send LoginCompleted (login model)`

How to write unit tests for this code? Specifically, I want to test my request builder.

Comment: If you want to test effects (like making an HTTP request), have a look at http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rogeriochaves/elm-testable/latest